# Uber jar not reading external properties files

Tags: java, maven, properties-file, maven-shade-plugin, maven-resources-plugin

I am creating an uber jar i.e. jar with dependencies for my project. I have a bunch of properties files that the project uses. I want to be able to change these properties files before running my project so i want them to be outside of the jar. Here is the relevant sections of my pom

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <configuration>

                    <artifactSet>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*.json</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </artifactSet>
                    <descriptorRefs>
                        <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                    </descriptorRefs>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <mainClass>path.to.main.Main</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Class-Path>.</Class-Path> 
                            <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>make-assembly</id> 
                        <phase>package</phase> 
                        <goals>
                            <goal>single</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${basedir}/target/conf</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>**/*.properties</include>
                                        <include>**/*.json</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

so essentially, I want to create a folder `${basedir}/target/conf` and copy all the `.properties` and `.json` files to it. Also, here is how I am reading the files

```
InputStream in = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("filename.properties");
```

I am facing a couple of problems

1. When i do `mvn clean install`, i still see the all the `.properties` and `.json` files in the `classes` folder. Shouldn't they have been **excluded**?
2. The `conf` folder is created with all of the files, but when I run the jar adn try to change the properties, the **changes are not picked up**. How can i ensure that the `conf` folder is being added to the classpath?
3. I want to be able to load the `.properties` and `.json` files from the `src/main/resources` folder while i am developing so i dont want to put them in a separate folder. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue where Uber jar is not reading the external configuration file.
I tried below configuration and it worked like charm. Refer below configuration it may help someone having the issue with uber jar not reading extenarl files.
I am not sure if this is the best way but haven't found any soultion online :)

1. I have included the resources using IncludeResourceTransformer.
2. Using filter removed the properties file from uber jar.
3. In classpath /conf reading the properties from external folder.

   ```
   <plugin>
           <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
           <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
           <version>2.3</version>
           <executions>            <!-- Run shade goal on package phase -->
               <execution>
                   <phase>package</phase>
                   <goals>
                       <goal>shade</goal>
                   </goals>
                   <configuration>
                       <transformers>
                           add Main-Class to manifest file
                           <transformer
                               implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                               <manifestEntries>
                                   <Main-Class>JobName</Main-Class>
                                   <Class-Path>conf/</Class-Path>
                               </manifestEntries>
                           </transformer>
                           <transformer
                               implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.IncludeResourceTransformer">
                               <resource>src/main/resources/config.properties</resource>
                               <file>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources/config.properties</file>
                           </transformer>
                       </transformers>
                       <finalName>FinalJarName</finalName>
                       <filters>
                           <filter>
                               <artifact>groupId:artifactId</artifact>
                               <excludes>
                                   <exclude>**/*.properties</exclude>
                               </excludes>
                           </filter>
                       </filters>
                   </configuration>
               </execution>
           </executions>
       </plugin>
   ```

good luck.